# How can I upload image into Cloudant?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, cloudant, nosql

I want to save profile image into Nosql DB Cloudant.

I know how to save firstname, lastame, and age but not an image using C#.

Comment: can you show some of your code?

Comment: HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler();
            handler.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password");
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient(handler)
 {
                BaseAddress = new Uri("https://username.cloudant.com/databasename/")
            };

Comment: this is for connecting to database in Cludant.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using one of the client libraries for C#/.NET listed [here](https://docs.cloudant.com/libraries.html#c#-/-.net). [This](https://github.com/danielwertheim/mycouch) one seems to be most promising. An example on how to use this is [here](https://github.com/cloudant/haengematte/blob/master/c%23/dotNet-45/Program.cs). According to their documentation you have to send the image in base64 string like below:

```
{
  "_id":"myprofile",
  "_attachments":
  {
    "myphoto.png":
    {
      "content_type":"image\/png",
      "data": "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"
    }
  }
}
```

Show us the code how you are reading the image in your program and I will try to elaborate on it.